# Force capitalization of terms on entry with Autocomplete Deluxe module

Tags: taxonomy-terms, ajax

I would like to force the capitalization of taxonomy term entries, or alternatively make them case insensitive so that 'book' and 'BOOK' are not different taxonomy terms. Is there a way to enable this. The context is this form http://www.wequest.co.uk/user/register on the 'skills' and 'resources' field... I need these to be standardised because they represent catalogues of skills and resources and I don't want duplicates either: of terms or due to different cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Taxonomy dupecheck](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_dupecheck) module would probably help for most of that (I'm not entirely sure about the case-sensitivity issue but give it a try; MySQL queries for term names will be case-insensitive so my gut instinct is this would work)

> Taxonomy dupecheck module prevents Drupal administrators from adding duplicate taxonomy vocabularies and/or terms. It's helpful when entering large amounts of terms or vocabularies in situations where each value must be unique. This saves time by preventing administrators from having to enforce a unique value policy through later cleanup of duplicate terms.

To force title-case on the term you could implement [`hook_taxonomy_term_presave()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.api.php/function/hook_taxonomy_term_presave/7) in a custom module and force it like so:

```
function MYMODULE_taxonomy_term_presave($term) {
  if (some_condition_applies_to($term)) {
    $term->name = ucwords($term->name); // Or ucfirst() depending on your requirement
  }
}
```

Comment: I have already installed this module, but I also would like to standardise, for cleanliness, the input to capitalisation. I have tried adding the css text-transform:capitalization to the form field, which looks like it works, but then the entries don't actually get saved with capitalization which is pretty weird...

Comment: The css method will only work on the client side, it won't change anything that's sent to the server. I've added some code to the answer that might help, it's untested but in theory it should do the trick

Comment: Hi clive, I don't this that hook_taxonomy_term_presave exists, but hook_taxonomy_term_save does would this still achieve the same result?

Comment: @Andrew It definitely exists, there's a link to it in the answer :) It's invoked from [`taxonomy_save()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_save/7)